# Notice: Undefined index: joinColumns doctrine 2 + symfony 2

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have the following structure of Entities in my project.
"SocieteDiffuseur" means CompanyDifuser, pays means country and Prix means Price.

```
class SocieteDiffuseur extends Societe
{

/**
* @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="MG\UtilityBundle\Entity\Pays", inversedBy="societeDiffuseur")
* @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false, name="pays_de_diffusion")
*/
protected $paysDiffs;
```

Country :

```
class Pays
{
/**
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="MG\UserBundle\Entity\SocieteDiffuseur", mappedBy="paysDiffs")
 */
private $societeDiffuseur;
```

Price :

```
class Prix
{
/**
* @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="MG\UtilityBundle\Entity\Pays")
* @ORM\JoinTable(name="prix_pays",
*                 joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="prix_id", referencedColumnName ="id")},
*                 inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="pays_id", referencedColumnName="id", unique=false)}
*                 )
*/
private $pays;
```

Ok, now i want the Price (prix) who have the same country (pays) than the company (societediffuseur).

So in my controller I was thinking I had to do:

```
$paysDiffs = $societe->getpaysDiffs();
$prix = $em->getRepository('MGVenteBundle:Prix')->findByPays($paysDiffs);
dump($prix); exit;
```

And i get this error : Notice: Undefined index: joinColumns.

So what should i do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$societe->getpaysDiffs();` returns an array. `findByPays()` requires an argument of type Pays, not an array.

What you need is to write a custom query to get the Prix-es you want. See here for more information about how to do that: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#querying-for-objects